# Android. Не меняется активити по нажатию кнопки

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!

Портирую свой клиент-серверный чат под Android.
У меня есть два активити с настройками либо клиента,
либо сервера, где по нажатию кнопки должны задаваться
параметры и активити меняется на другой. Но проблема в
том, что активити не меняется. Я закомментировал большую
часть кода всех трех активити, но не помогло.

Вот часть кода(только клиентская часть, ибо в
инициализации они схожи):

ClientSetting:

```
public class ClientSettings extends AppCompatActivity {

  private EditText edit_nickname;
  private EditText edit_serverIP;
  private String nickname;
  private String serverIP;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_settings);

    edit_nickname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_nickname);
    edit_serverIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_serverIP);
    Button btn_connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);

    View.OnClickListener listenerConnect = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            nickname = edit_nickname.getText().toString();
            serverIP = edit_serverIP.getText().toString();

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_functional);
        }
    };

    btn_connect.setOnClickListener(listenerConnect);
  }
}
```

FunctionalActivity:

```
public class FunctionalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  static private EditText edit_msg;
  static private Button btn_send;
  static private TextView msgBox;
  static private String msg;
  private Client client;
  private Server server;
  static private String nickname;
  static private String serverIP;
  static private String serverName;
  static private String maxConnections;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_functional);

    View.OnClickListener listenerSend = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            msg = edit_msg.getText().toString();
        }
    };
  }

  static String waitAndGetMsg() {
    while (true) {
        if (btn_send.callOnClick()) {
            if (!msg.isEmpty()) {
                return msg;
            }
        }
    }
  }

  public static void msgBoxSetText(String str) {
    msgBox.setText(str);
  }

  static void msgBoxAddText(String str) {
    msgBox.append(str);
  }
}
```

**UPD:** Экспериментируя, я узнал, что оказывается из ClientSettings и ServerSettings ВООБЩЕ не меняется активити

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `ClientSettings`, при обработке `OnClickListener` **удалите** `setContentView(R.layout.activity_functional);` и **добавьте** вызов `activity`

---

**Пример:**

```
View.OnClickListener listenerConnect = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            nickname = edit_nickname.getText().toString();
            serverIP = edit_serverIP.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, FunctionalActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent); // вызов другой activity
        }
    };
```

---

[Изучите](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/58-urok-21-sozdanie-i-vyzov-activity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_functional);
```

Нужно написать

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FunctionalActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```